# Why won't my mac discover devices in this Core Bluetooth App?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I've been working on a Core Bluetooth Mac app and I've run into issues with the discovery part on the Mac. This code has failed to to discovery any devices despite the fact that the very same devices appear in the bluetooth setting of my mac. Obviously it's a code issue but I can't seem to figure it out. Code:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: NSViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

func setupBT() {

}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    var statusMessage = ""
    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOn:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Turned On"

    case .poweredOff:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Turned Off"

    case .resetting:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Resetting"

    case .unauthorized:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Not Authorized"

    case .unsupported:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Not Supported"

    default:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Unknown"
    }

    print(statusMessage)
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("Discovered")
}
}
```

It is printing out "turned on" but not "discovered". I tried multiple bluetooth devices and speakers.

Comment: You haven't told CoreBluetooth to discover any devices. You need to call `scanForPeripherals`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`scanForPeripherals(withServices:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518986-scanforperipherals) in order to discover peripherals. Please note that you have to wait for `CBCentralManager` to be in `poweredOn` state. Otherwise, nothing will happen and you might see some warning and error logs in the console.